# Get same rows within a table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok i have table with this structure:

`order_id` `product_id` `price`

`18645` `289` `5.90`

`18644` `219` `1.80`

`18644` `109` `2.30`

`18643` `289` `4.50`

`18642` `180` `9.80`

`18642` `190` `3.40`

How i'm able to count same `product_id's` from a range of `order_id's` along with their according total prices per group of `product_ids` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the product wise `COUNT` and `SUM` you need to use [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) `GROUP BY` product_id:

```
SELECT product_id,
       COUNT(1) AS product_count,
       SUM(price) AS total_price
FROM table_name
WHERE order_id BETWEEN 18642  AND 18645
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_count ASC, total_price ASC
```

Comment: you're welcome. If you got your answer then don't forget to accept the best answer.

Comment: ORDER BY product_count ASC / ORDER BY total_price ASC doesn't seem to work. Why is that?

Comment: There is something else i would like to ask you Omesh if i may. So now we group them by product id and count their appropriate price. Is there any way i could group the already grouped product ids according to another table which categorize the product ids? I dont know if i made my self clear but please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes sure you can group it with another table using `INNER JOIN` query on both the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
       COUNT(product_id) totalCount,
       SUM(price) totalPrice
FROM tableName
WHERE Order_ID BETWEEN 00001  AND 99999
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You need to just group by product_id

```
select product_id,
       count(*) as count ,
       sum(price) as price
from   <table>
where  order_id beteen <val1> and <val2>
group by product_id
```

Comment: Thanks Joe G Josheph, much appreciated!